# Error in my code that I cannot find, beginner program

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python and I am following video instruction on verson 3 and using the latest Pycharm IDE.

My screen looks like the instructor's screen, but I could have tunnel vision from staring at it too long. His code executes perfectly while mine crashes. What am I missing?

Error message:

```
line 6, in <module>
    balance = float(input("OK, ", name, ". Please enter the cost of the ", item, ": "))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5
```

First part of the program up to line 6:

```
# Get information from user

print("I'll help you determine how long you will need to save.")
name = input("What is your name? ")
item = input("What is it that you are saving up for? ")
balance = float(input("OK, ", name, ". Please enter the cost of the ", item, ": "))
```

The pycharm version is:

> PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.4 Build #PC-145.1504, built on May
>   25, 2016 JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86 JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by
>   Oracle Corporation

Now, am I just blind or is there a possible ide issue that could have happened in a minor update between my version and the instructor's version, he is teaching python 3.

Many thanks in advance for any help that anyone can throw out.

Comment: Like the error message says, `input` takes a single arg. So put most of that stuff into a `print` call, and just leave the`": "` as the `input` prompt.

Comment: You're probably confusing the `,` with the concatenation operator `+` in your `input()` -- change all the `,` to `+` and you should be fine.

Comment: `input expected at most 1 arguments, got 5` you are passing 5 arguments, you should be passing 1.

Comment: Michael, the consensus is that we're not sure why the instructor's version works.  Either he's doing something different from what you've shown or perhaps he has redefined the input method.  See the other comments for an explanation of how to do string contentation using the '+' operator.

Comment: This is a pretty common issue where new programmers assume that `print` and `input` can be used the same way but one waits for input, unfortunately `input` has a much more restricted call signature, if you are sure that your prof's code is passing multiple arguments to `input` then the rest of your class is probably facing the same issues you are so I'd recommend asking the prof about this problem.

Comment: "Michael, the consensus is that we're not sure why the instructor's version works."

Looking at the program again, it is slide based and not real shots from an IDE. Most probably power point or some other tool.

Chaps my ars that they didn't test the code considering that they state, on this very lesson multiple times, that you should test your code often yet...here this is.

Would the way that I initially listed work with Python 2? Is that the possible source of the issue? Maybe the slide maker was a master of version 2 but the lecturer has you use python 3.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the `input` operator takes a single input (the string that you would like to display). Also in Python, string concatenation is done with the `+` operator. In your current operation, you are passing 5 separate strings rather than the 1 that you want to use. Change that line of code to:

```
balance = float(input("OK, "+ name +". Please enter the cost of the" + item + ": "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("I'll help you determine how long you will need to save.")
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
item = raw_input("What is it that you are saving up for? ")
balance = float(raw_input("OK, "+ name +". Please enter the cost of the "+ item +": "))
print name
print item
print balance
```

Comment: the OP is clearly using python 3 where `input` is used to get a string instead of `raw_input`, and the `print` function requires `()` parenthesis like every other function

Answer (score 0):

A little rewrite may clarify

```
input_message = "OK, {name}. Please enter the cost of the {item}: ".format(name=name, item=item)
balance = float(input(input_message))
```

The argument to `input` should be just a string, which I build using `format` https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

You are passing 5 objects, say:

- `"OK, "`
- `name`
- `". "Please enter the cost of the "`
- `item`
- `": "`

therefore the the `TypeError`

Take into account that you should validate the actual input to be converted into a float, if I type "foobar" as input, the above line will give a `ValueError` as you can check by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a string format operator `%s`.  `%` is a reserved character that you can drop right into the input string.  The s that follows the `%` formats the variable, if possible, into a string. If you need an integer just use `%d`.  Then list the variables in order of appearance in the string preceded by the `%`

```
balance = float(input("OK %s. Please enter the cost of the %s: " %(name,item)))
```

You just have to be careful not to change integers or floats into strings unless you want that to happen which I don't recommend doing in an input statement.

Comment: Thanks all! The '+' in place of ',' solved the problem. Now what is really bothering me is how that mistake made it into the lectures that I am watching!